# How do I traverse till class multi

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="awe-ajaxcheckboxlist-field awe-field form-control">
  <input name="MFTestName" id="MFTestName" class="awe-val awe-array" type="hidden" disabled="disabled" value="">
  <div class="awe-display">
    <div class="inputCont" style="display: none;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="" name="MFTestName">
    </div>
    <div class="odropdown">
      <div class="odisplay">
        <div class="multi">
          <span class="aption">Select MF test(s)</span>
          <input type="text" class="osearch awe-il">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get to class multi to change its CSS.
I did like this

```js
$("div.multi").css("background-color", "red");
```

But this will change color to red for the multi select components. I want color change to happen only to component with id `MFTestName`.

Comment: `$("#MFTestName").css("background-color", "red")` ?

Comment: I did like this now $('#MFTest').find(".multi").css({ 'background-color': '#ffeeee' }); and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: ID `MFTestName` isn't in the DIV with class `multi`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: <div class="col-md-3" id="MFTest">
        <label for="MFTestName">MF Test:</label>

Comment: This is the DIV which had class multi which is missed here. I got it working.  Thank you.